# iOS Safari WebApp opens links in new window

Tags: ios, meta-tags, turbolinks, address-bar

I've added meta tags to my web app to make it fullscreen if added to the iPhone home, it works but only on the first page visited (If I add page 2 to my home, page 2 won't have the address bar, but any new page will). When I navigate to a new page, it shows a bar with the address, option to close (return to previous page) and read options. I'm using turbolinks, if I disable it, when I click on any link (a simple `<a href="page.html"`>) it opens up Safari instead of staying in the web app.

Is there any way to keep navigation within the home app?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
```

[image: Home]

[image: Page]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should add a manifest (see: https://web.dev/add-manifest/) and make sure it holds the 'scope' directive. Set it to - at least - your domainname or a / if you want to make it relative.